# 15.10 Dell XPS 15 (9550) External Monitor not waking

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, monitor, 15.10

I'm in Ubuntu 15.10, with Kernel 4.3. Things are working better than I could ever imagine. Other than ONE bug...

When my laptop turns off it's screen and my external monitor's screen (I have it set for 5 minutes, in case I forget to lock the laptop), The external monitor never wakes up.

I have it hooked up with an HDMI to DVI cable. It works perfect other then it not waking up.

If I reboot with the cable plugged in, it still doesn't wake up.

If I unplug it and reboot, it wakes up.

The strange thing is that, I think Ubuntu thinks it did wake up. The reason I say that is because it doesn't gather my windows into the main screen until I unplug the HDMI cable. I even see the screen flicker as if the driver noticed a cable has been unplugged and it needs to do something.

So my questions are: Anyone know how to fix this? Or, if anything, know a command line command to wake the 2nd monitor?

Thanks!

EDIT: This might be fixed in kernel 4.7 [per this article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.7-Intel-DP-Plus-Plus).

EDIT: This still happens with a standard HDMI cable.

Comment: I've found that if I suspend the laptop, and wake it, then the 2nd monitor comes right up. So this only happens when it turns off the screen and the laptop is not suspended.

Comment: For some reason, suspend stopped working. I'm really struggling with this. I almost think it's because I'm using an HDMI->DVI cable.

Comment: Same problem, also Dell XPS 15 9550, also HDMI->DVI cable.

Comment: Same issue here. Brand new XPS15/i7/16/512, using hdmi-hdmi cable on Dell P2314T touch screen, from hdmi output  (no usb-c dock), that is the only thing connected (+usb for touch) After dimming display for over a certain period of time (not right away), the external screen is not waking up, while touch still works on the external desktop canvas. Repeated the same error on both, Ubuntu and original Windows 10 Pro that came preinstalled. Reconnecting hdmi again wakes the screen up, but this is a fuckup since all my windows are placed on main again. For a 2,5k laptop I'd not expect that!!!